# facebook og:image tag not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hope you can help.

For some reasons facebook debugger tool is showing warning "og:image could not be downloaded or is too small". Image size is 1292 *1292 .

[url fb check](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fesocializ.w.verdikt.com.au%2FFacebook%2FProfile%2Fb331bdff-bcda-4967-b29c-7b1270453c4c%3FeventId%3D95137020-bf47-4334-b91d-93e760681797%26facebookId%3D179998847830%26picId%3D00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)

og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to rescrape the "Canonical URL".

Comment: Could you please explain why I need to rescrape the Canonical URL. I am posting link to a profile page programmatically when ever a user uploads a pic to my application. How can I remove the warning without rescraping canonical url each  time a user uploads a pic